Wiremock random response with different status code to the same request
I'm using wiremock, I have several responses for the same path and method, get /one. I would like to respond with different status code randomly. I know I can differ the response sequentially using scenarios, but not randomly. I'm talking about doing it directly in json configuration, not using JAVA wiremock API.
For example, I would know how to respond the sequence [200,400,401,200,400,401...etc] but not a random one like [400, 200, 401, 200, 400, 400..etc]

Unfortunately, this isn't possible in WireMock at the moment.  I think the only way to achieve this is to build your own extension to return the status codes in the order you want.  The only other option is the scenarios feature, but as you say, this doesn't quite go as far as you are looking for.
If you are thinking of writing your own response transformer then this page might be of some use to you - https://wiremock.org/docs/extensibility/transforming-responses/

have you try using PickRandomHelper ?
https://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#pick-random-helper
e.g.
{{{pickRandom '200' '400' '404' '500' '503'}}}

